# How to save QTextStream in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

I have to read a text file in Qt line by line.

So I made a function that reads first `X` lines of the file. But when the function is called next time **I want the reading to start from line X + 1**. I know that I can do this just by skipping the first `X` lines.

But I tried to save the `QTextStream` object which gives me the error:

in expansion of macro `Q_DISABLE_COPY`.

and if I save the pointer to `QTextStream` object, then my application hangs. Does this mean that skipping first `X` lines is the only way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save the stream's current position using `pos()` and then `seek(position)` to resume from the previous reached point.

I suspect your `QTextStream` is created on the stack each time you read, which is why if you try using a pointer to it the next time it crashes, because it is a dangling pointer pointing to a no longer valid object.

So you either need to make the text stream persistent, so either implement it is a member variable or allocate it on the heap with `new` which will work with a pointer, or simply create a new text stream and seek to the previous position.